# Android : Designing Map for the 2D Game World/Background

Tags: android, opengl-es, dictionary

I have problem on designing map for Android games.. I'm planning to make the map scroll when the character moves.. I'm thinking if I make the map large enough to scroll the file size will be large and is that acceptable?
or is there another trick to design the map?

Note : I'm rendering it using OpenGL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up "tiled" maps. That means you have pieces of the map that repeat and you only save the minimum information needed for displaying. For example if you have a map of gras and water of 200x200 pixels, you'd only need 200x200 bits, either 1 (=grass) or 0(=water). Then you load a single grass and a single water graphic and put them together based on your information.

Comment: what if my map has more element like road, town or some circle?
I`m handling code section in my games and my friend handle the graphic setction.. So I`m a beginner in graphic terms

Comment: Then you need more different tiles and a larger tile id. Imagine Plains, Wood, Hills, Mountains and City. You have one 32x32 graphic for each. You have a 2d array of integers from 0 (Plains) to 4 (City). Foreach array index, you draw the 32x32 graphic. Your map can be huge, you only need an int per cell, not the whole graphic.

Comment: will the image will still looks good or it will be like the mario background map?

Comment: That depends on how many different tiles you have and how good they look. Obviously having a map of blue and green rectangles will look shitty, having a map of hand-drawn, shader animated pictures looks great.

Comment: I`m sorry to keep asking.. But do you have any article or guide on how to implement tiled map using eclipse?I have looked into tiled map and most of them is tutorial how to do it in some engine..